# Why does this while loop code not work even though the entered value makes the condition false?

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  double morningR;

  printf("Morning rating (0.0-5.0): "); // Ask morning first
  morningR = scanf("%lf", &morningR); 
        
  while (morningR < 0.0 || morningR > 5.0) {
    printf("   Morning rating (0.0-5.0): "); // Ask morning again
    morningR = scanf("%lf", &morningR); 
  }
```

If I enter 6.5 or -0.9, the while loop should ask the question again, but it doesn't.

Comment: `morningR = scanf("%lf", &morningR);` Why?

Comment: So the entered value can be stored in the morningR variable

Comment: The entered value is stored in `morningR` by `scanf`. That's why you pass the address `&morningR` as an argument. But then why assign the return value of `scanf` to `morningR = ...`?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't worry, mental typos happen. Speaking of the return value of `scanf`, however, it is a good habit to check it to make sure that `scanf` has indeed read all the expected inputs. In this case, something like `if(scanf("%lf", &morningR) != 1) { /* oops */ }`.

Comment: That's a great idea. I'll definitely do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns the number of receiving arguments successfully assigned or EOF so `morningR = scanf(...)` is wrong. In your case `mornigR` will be assigned `1` because `scanf` successfully read 1 value and your `while` is never entered.

This sort of bug is so easily found by debugging. If you would have debugged your code you would have immediately seen that `morningR` does not have the value you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work now

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  double morningR;

  printf("Morning rating (0.0-5.0): "); // Ask morning first
  scanf("%lf", &morningR); 
        
  while (morningR < 0.0 || morningR > 5.0) {
    printf("   Morning rating (0.0-5.0): "); // Ask morning again
    morningR = scanf("%lf", &morningR); 
  }
```

Answer (score -3):

1. Write `Clrscr();` and `getch();`
2. Try To Use `int`
3. Write 0 and 5 instead of 0.0 and 5.0.
4. don't write `morningR = scanf("%lf", &morningR);`
   write only

   ```
   scanf("%d", &morningR);
   ```

(`%d` for `int`)

Comment: All four of those are horrible ideas

Comment: But the `morningR = scanf("%lf", &morningR);` part is still wrong. Just write `scanf("%lf", &morningR);`. `scanf` returns the amount of values successfully read, which is good for checking your input, but not how you used it.

Comment: morningR is defined

Comment: by scanf we are adding value in moringR